# lualatex and unicode-math

Tags: hyperref, luatex, babel, unicode-math, scrartcl

In this MWE

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[spanish, activeacute]{babel} 
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\section{A section}
\begin{equation}
    j =\sqrt{-1}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

there is a fatal error. Any help? Thanks

Comment: don't use activeacute.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, thanks. I know it is possible to have not an error without activeacute but  I don't know the reason. Can you give me an idea?

Comment: activeacute makes the ' active but unicode-math tries to setup it at begin document too. You can try to load unicode-math before babel, but imho there is no reason for the option -- nowadays you should be able to input the accented chars directly.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer thanks for your comment. Always it's good to learn something. I'm going to eliminate activacute in the babel's option.

Comment: @jpayansomet there are several bugs in Spanish babel. The safer way to use it is `\usepackage[english, spanish, es-noshorthands, shorthands=off]{babel}` (thanks to Javier Bezos), see https://github.com/latex3/babel/issues/38

Comment: @UlrikeFischer with TeXLive 2017/babel 3.18 it does not give any error tough --- it errors out with a current TeXLive 2019 up-to-date to this morning...

Comment: @Rmano quite possible. But unless you know a good use case why you want to use the activeacute option nowadays I would simply drop it and not try to find work around to avoid clashes with other package not expecting an active `'`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I agree with you --- I find that the shorthand stuff in babel (that was a life safer 20 years ago) is nowadays better off completely.

Comment: @Rmano thanks for your comments. Do you think it's a good idea to switch to polyglossia package? In fact, I use only lualatex.